# how to authenticate socket.io websockets with user password and developer password

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I need to authenticate socket.io client connections with the client's username, password and additionally with developer password (developer password is used to ensure that the service is only used by the apps developed by registered developers).

The problem is, developer password should not be seen by the application's user or the client. Is there a way to authenticate the user with client username, password and additionally developer password, without client knowing the developer password? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason the client can't know the developer password? I assume that "client" and "developer" are one and the same? If so, is the reason commercial (like: the person who got issued the password, and the actual person writing the client code, are different people?). Can the client know *another* secret, like a token you'll generate for them, a certificate, etc?

Comment: @NitzanShaked dev password is for the developer to use the service when developing an app. If the users/clients of the application that is developed by the dev, gets to know the dev password, then they also will use the service. Here the client refers to the person who uses the application developed by the developer.

Comment: Well then, the way I see it you have 2 options: one is do what some apps do (e.g. Urban Airship), and *do* have the developer's secret inside the app, where the client can see it. However, this secret can only perform very specific operations, and in order to perform more privileged, app-wide operations (as opposed to specific-customer operations) the developer uses a "developer master secret", which is only stored on the developer's machine. Another option -- in the next comment.

Comment: Another option is that the developer's server-side code will authenticate the end-user, and when that happens the developer server-side code calls an API on your end to generate a "session token" for the specific end-user on the specific developer's app. Something like "DeveloperId:EndUserId:HMAC-That-You-Generate". This token is then returned to the end-user, which uses that token to invoke services on your back-end. You can validate that token (regenerate the HMAC given DeveloperId and EndUserId, and compare to the hash you were given HMAC).